# What does the PCA similarity factor tell us?

Tags: time-series, python, pca, similarities, cosine-similarity

I found the following formula for comparing time series

$$ S_{\mathrm{PCA}}^{\lambda}=\frac{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} \sum \limits_{j=1}^{k}\left(\lambda_{i}^{(1)} \lambda_{j}^{(2)}\right) \cos ^{2} \theta_{i j}}{\sum \limits_{i=1}^{k} \lambda_{i}^{(1)} \lambda_{i}^{(2)}} $$

where PCA is applied to two data sets (or time series) $X_1$ and $X_2$ so that $\lambda_{i}^{(1)}$ is the eigenvalue of the $ith$ eigenvector (principal component) of the first data set $X_1$, respectively for $\lambda_{j}^{(2)}$ and $\theta_{i j}$ is the angle between the $ith$ eigenvector of $X_1$ and $jth$ eigenvector of $X_2$. I use this formula to compare the similarity of the time series of trajectories and the similarity factor is around $0.8$ for each pair of 100s of time series but I don't quite get what the score means. Could anyone explain to me what exactly is calculated here and how we can conclude how similar the data sets are?

The Python code:

```
def pca_similarity_factor(ts1: np.array, ts2: np.array, components = 3) -> float:
        pca1 = PCA(n_components=components)
        pca2 = PCA(n_components=components)
        pca1.fit(ts1)
        pca2.fit(ts2)
        len_ev = len(pca1.explained_variance_)
        data1 = zip(pca1.explained_variance_, pca1.components_)
        data2 = zip(pca2.explained_variance_, pca2.components_)
        numerator = sum([ev1*ev2*(np.cos(angle_between(v1,v2))**2) for ev1,v1 in data1 for ev2,v2 in data2])
        denominator = sum([pca1.explained_variance_[i] * pca2.explained_variance_[i] for i in range(len_ev)])
        similarity_factor = numerator/denominator
        return similarity_factor
        

def unit_vector(vector):
    return vector / np.linalg.norm(vector)

def angle_between(v1, v2):
    v1_u = unit_vector(v1)
    v2_u = unit_vector(v2)
    return np.arccos(np.clip(np.dot(v1_u, v2_u), -1.0, 1.0))
```

Here is the source: Singhal, A. and Seborg, D.E. (2005), [Clustering multivariate time-series data](https://doi.org/10.1002/cem.945). J. Chemometrics, 19: 427-438.

Comment: An aside from the stats: You're already using NumPy for some of the math and there are further steps of your calculation that can be vectorized.

Comment: @Galen Yes, you are right. I still have to do that